# Removing the three dots from the end of the excerpt

Tags: php, css, function

So I am trying to remove the three dots from the end of my excerpt on my blog but without success. I have gone into the **functions.php** file and it seems to be blank:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return '[ ]';
```

I have also had a look at another css file called **blog-functions.php** and can't seem to crack what is outputting the...

Thank you :-)

http://demo.boxofficeboxing.co.uk/news/

http://demo.boxofficeboxing.co.uk/?s=

Comment: There’s a CSS rule `.eltd-post-excerpt::after` somewhere – delete that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you have to add one css for that in child theme style.css

you found css in modules.min.css file

```
.eltd-post-excerpt:after {
  position: relative;
  content: '...';
}
```

so you have just override that css with this given css and dots are remove.

```
.eltd-post-excerpt:after {
    content: ' '; 
}
```

Hope this work as you want.

Thank You

Comment: Your Welcome Bro... @Dee